# Laravel file upload not working on mobile

Tags: php, laravel, file

I have a form that ask a use to upload the picture and this is built on laravel 5.2.The form on my desktop works fine and when i try to use my mobile to upload pictures they are not recognized as the validator fails with no picture uploaded any suggestions welcome for clarity here is my code

```
$destinationPath = 'uploads'; 
// upload path
$extension = Input::file('picture')->getClientOriginalExtension(); 
// getting image extension
$fileName = rand(11111,99999).'.'.$extension; 
// renameing image
Input::file('picture')->move($destinationPath, $fileName); 
// uploading file to given path
```

Comment: Which plug-in are you using for uploading the picture in client-side form?

Comment: no plug in just raw code php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public function uploadPicture(Request $request){
        $picture = $request->file('picture');
        if($picture->isValid()){
            $destinationPath = public_path() . '/uploads/';
            $picture_name = time() . '-' . str_random(15) . '.' .  
                            $picture->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $picture->move($destinationPath, $picture_name);
        }

    }
```

Comment: tried that but still can not get it to work on mobile like I said before works fine on desktop  environment but on the mobile the input file field is empty added the java script to see the file uploaded that works as well but the picture is still missing even if i can see it its been uploaded

Comment: Can you share what you are getting $request->all().

Comment: Have retested on a different mobile Iphone and it  worked fine but the android device would not pick up the upload

Comment: From android side which format you are uploading image ?

Answer (score 1):

This is for others who need help with this, just go to `php.ini` in `xampp` and change the following to this:

```
upload file size max:
upload_max_filesize = 50M
post_max_size = 50M
max_input_time = 300 
max_execution_time = 300
```

this worked for me.

Comment: Do you also have an explanation why increasing the size would help if uploads from a desktop work, but not from a mobile?

Comment: @RalfFriedl Most of the images on a mobile device will be from the camera - mine takes 10+ megabyte images. Most of the images on my laptop are substantially smaller - memes, images I downloaded off Facebook, etc. Might be why.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is upload_max_filesize because a lot of devices capture photos on High Resolution and pictures weigh a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I see this is a little old but I'd recommend a few steps:

1. Update Laravel version if possible
2. Handle image upload with Intervention - this will fix orientation issues when uploading from mobile
3. Check your file size config in php.ini

More details here:
https://bdigital.asia/en/insights/upload-ios-image-laravel-php/